# How to convert ArrayList<Integer> into the int[] without using the for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am using the following way but I got an error

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(5);

    int[] arr = list.toArray();
}
```

The error I got is

```
java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to int[]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use another option of toArray method which takes empty array as argument.

```
Integer[] arr =  new Integer[list.size()];
list.toArray(arr);
```

Integer class support all operations available for int data type

Comment: I believe that the OP wisely prefers an array of primitive `int`.

Answer (score 1):

> toArray() method returns an array of type Object(Object[]). We need to
> typecast it to Integer before using as Integer objects. If we do not
> typecast, we get compilation error.

This would work fine

```
Object[] objects = list.toArray();
```

For getting directly int array, you can use streams() method of list and mapToInt() to convert ArrayList to array of primitive data type int

```
int[] arr = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```